How can I set plots to display below their respective code chunks when using quarto interactively in VSCode
Currently VSCode displays plots and all output in the Interactive pane when I am working in VSCode. I would like the plots and output to display below the code chunks that generate them when I am working interactively in VSCode Editor. Is this possible? I have scoured the internet and am finding no solutions.

This is an ongoing issue. If you want inline chunks like Rstudio you have to do things in an .ipynb file and then use quarto render. See this ongoing discussion and this related issue
